# How do I update index in recyclerview on next button functionality

Tags: android

this is recyclerview where I am selecting the option and saving in activity but I want to select 
only one option but it is selecting multiple this is the problem, and how to apply mainIndex I am handling in activity and then notify adapter.

```
   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ExamQuestionViewHolder holder, int i) {

   final ExamQuestionsOptionsItem item = itemList.get(i);

   if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getOption()) && item.getOption() != null){
    holder.tvOption.setText(item.getOption());
   }else {
        holder.tvOption.setText("");
    }
    holder.rlMain.setSelected(item.isSelected());

    holder.rlMain.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,
            item.isSelected() ? R.drawable.preference_bg_selected : R.drawable.rect_box_white));

    holder.rlMain.setAlpha(0.6f);

    holder.tvOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.rlMain.performClick();
        }
    });

    holder.tvOption.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,
            item.isSelected() ? R.color.colorPrimary : R.color.font_color));
```

selecting options

```
    holder.rlMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (!isClickable)return;
            holder.rlMain.setAlpha(0.6f);
            item.setSelected(!item.isSelected());

            holder.tvOption.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,
                    item.isSelected() ? R.color.colorPrimary : R.color.font_color));

            holder.rlMain.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,
                    item.isSelected() ? R.drawable.preference_bg_selected : 
            R.drawable.rect_box_white));

            if (item.isSelected()){
                selectedOptionList.add(item.getOptionId());
            }else {
                if (selectedOptionList != null)
                selectedOptionList.remove(item.getOptionId());
            }
            if (selectedOptionList != null)
            selectedOptionListner.selectedOptionList(selectedOptionList);
           }
       });

     }
```

activity calling questions, answer options are appearing in recyclerview and question is in activity textview

```
    protected void fetchQuestions() {
       viewsDisable();
    Call<ExamQuestionResponse> call = 
    ApiClient.getInstance().getMainApi().getExamQuestions(Util.getHeaderMap(token), examId);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ExamQuestionResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ExamQuestionResponse> call, Response<ExamQuestionResponse> 
            response) {
            viewsEnable();
            if (response.body() != null) {
                ExamQuestionResponse mResponse = response.body();
                if (mResponse.isStatus()) {
                    questionList = mResponse.getData();
                    if (questionList != null && questionList.size() > 0) {
                        binding.tvQuestion.setText(questionList.get(mainIndex).getQuestion());
                        adapter = new ExamQuestionAdapter(ExamQuestionsActivity.this, optionList,
                                new ExamQuestionAdapter.RecyclerViewClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void recyclerViewListClicked(View v, int position) {
                                        //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    }
                                }, new ExamQuestionAdapter.SelectedOptionList() {
                            @Override
                            public void selectedOptionList(ArrayList<String> list) {
                                selectedOptionList = list;
                            }
                        });
                        binding.recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
                    } else {
                        dataNotFound();
                    }

                } else {
                    dataNotFound();
                }

            } else {
                dataNotFound();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ExamQuestionResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            viewsEnable();

          }
       });
    }

   // next button in activity, question is updating because i have mainIndex but option are in 
    // recyclerview they are not updating 
     binding.tvNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mainIndex++;
            binding.tvQuestion.setText("");
            binding.tvQuestion.setText(questionList.get(mainIndex).getQuestion());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Comment: are you using the position, "i" as second param of bindviewholder, 
using that position index (comparing with item.isSelected logic) will work for item clicked at position in list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the question I was not using proper indexes to move the index on button click.
I have used index++ or index-- on next and previous button click.

```
protected void showNextQuestion() {

    boolean isAnyItemSelect = false;
    List<ExamQuestionsOptionsItem> optionsItems = 
    examQuestionDataItemList.get(currentIndex).getOptions();
    prefConfig.saveOptionsItem(optionsItems);
    for (int i = 0; i < optionsItems.size(); i++) {
        if (optionsItems.get(i).isSelected()) {
            isAnyItemSelect = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!isAnyItemSelect) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please select any answer before proceeding", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    if (currentIndex == questionListSize - 1) {
        showFinishAlert(this.getString(R.string.exam_going_to_finish));

    } else {
        currentIndex++;
        prefConfig.writeRecoverIndex(currentIndex);

        if(isReview && !examQuestionDataItemList.get(currentIndex).isReview() )
        {
            showNextQuestion();
            return;
        }


        setQuestions();
    }
}
```